# How to change the splash animation of buttons in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Current splash animation takes a lot of time to cover the whole body if the button has a large width ( it can be observed during a long press and animation is limited to the small surrounding area of the touch for a short press ). Is there any way to make the splash animation faster and cover the whole button no matter where you touch?

See the attached gif where the splash animation slowly covers the button when you long press. How to make the splash animation cover the whole button faster?

[image: Current splash animation]

```
final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 90, vertical: 32),
      child:Text('Click me')), onPressed: () {}),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add code snippet or gif of your current code

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede There is nothing to add I am talking about the default behaviour.... I have edited the question for more clarification.

Comment: @someuser  I have considered that but I would prefer a faster animation if possible

Comment: @someuser my bad,  I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Here I have tried to do this please check.

```
ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(text),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            overlayColor:MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xff727272)) ,//change with your color
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ))),
          onPressed: (){},
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iOS splash animation which covers the whole button immediately, if you use `CupertinoButton()` instead of  `ElevatedButton()`

Probably a little too late, but maybe there will be someone else with the same question in the future.

Comment: Yeah a little late haha. I would have accepted the answer but I no longer work with this tech so cant verify the answer.